# Gutenberg Block -> Media Upload - Array of different images

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

Someone could help me create array for images inside attributes?

At the moment I did:

```
attributes: {
    Bg_URL: { type: 'string' },
    Bg_ID: { type: 'number' },
    Bg_ALT: { type: 'string'},
    icon_1_URL: { type: 'string' },
    icon_1_ID: { type: 'number' },
    icon_1_ALT: { type: 'string'},
    icon_2_URL: { type: 'string' },
    icon_2_ID: { type: 'number' },
    icon_2_ALT: { type: 'string'},
    icon_3_URL: { type: 'string' },
    icon_3_ID: { type: 'number' },
    icon_3_ALT: { type: 'string'},
},
```

Then Update function:

```
const onSelectImage = (name) => (e) => {
        setAttributes({
            [name+'_URL']: e.url,
            [name+'_ID']: e.id,
            [name+'_ALT']: e.alt,
        });
    };
```

And MediaUpload:

```
<MediaUpload
    onSelect={onSelectImage('Bg')}
    type="image"
    value={attributes.Bg_ID}
    render={({open}) => (
        <figure className={!attributes.Bg_ID ? ' image-button' : ' image-preview'} onClick={open} >
            {!attributes.Bg_ID ? __("Upload Image") : <img src={attributes.Bg_URL} />}
        </figure>
    )}
/>
```

So ok, I did one function to update the specific image in attributes, but I would like to have images array there, which would store all block images, and from onSelect I could pass name/id/key of that image to store, which I would call

```
images.key.url
```

Ideally I would see the same for RichText, where I don't need to define each of it separate, but would have a array "content", and there something like this?

```
value={ attributes.content.heading }
onChange={ ( content.heading ) => setAttributes( { content.heading } ) }
```

where .heading don't need to be defined earlier, it is when adding the content.

Have anyone had the same idea and could help to archive that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest storing the images in an array attribute. Then you can use the `MediaUpload` component to create and edit a "gallery".

The `onSelectMeida` function:

```js
const onSelectMedia = (media) => {
    setAttributes({
        images: [{
            id: media.id,
            url: media.url,
            alt: media.alt,
        }],
    });
};
```

The `MediaUpload` component:

```
<MediaUploadCheck>
    <MediaUpload
        multiple={ true }
        gallery={ true }
        onSelect={ (media) => onSelectMedia(media) }
        allowedTypes={ ['image'] }
        accept="image/*"
        value={ images.map(item => item.id) }
        render={ ({open}) => {
            return (
                <Fragment>
                    <Button
                        isPrimary={ true }
                        onClick={ (event) => {
                            event.stopPropagation();
                            open();
                        } }
                    >
                        { images.length > 0 ? __('Edit Images', 'pb') : __('Select Images', 'pb') }
                    </Button>
                </Fragment>
            );
        } }
    />
</MediaUploadCheck>
```

Then you can render the images using a `map`:

```
{ images.length > 0 && images.map(image => {
    <img    
        key={ image.id }
        src={ image.url }
        alt={ image.alt }
    />
}) }
```